# Bitbucket Pull Request refspec

Tags: jenkins, bitbucket

I've searched Atlassian docs and found this `ref/pull-requests/$PR_NO/from` and when I try to fetch that, I encounter this error `Couldn't find remote ref refs/pull-requests/1/from`. Is there a way to enable this ref? Or are webhooks the only option? I am trying a CI setup with Bitbucket.

(We're on the 10-user paid plan)

Answer (score 7):

This is now possible. You just need to add a line like this to your `<repo_root>/.git/config`:

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = ...
    fetch = ...
    fetch = +refs/pull-requests/*:refs/pull-requests/*
```

When you fetch, you'll see a whole new set of refs appear:

```
$ git fetch origin
remote: Counting objects: 252, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (48/48), done.
remote: Total 82 (delta 20), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (82/82), done.
From ...
 * [new ref]           refs/pull-requests/300/from  -> refs/pull-requests/300/from
 * [new ref]           refs/pull-requests/300/merge -> refs/pull-requests/300/merge
 * [new ref]           refs/pull-requests/302/from  -> refs/pull-requests/302/from
 * [new ref]           refs/pull-requests/323/from  -> refs/pull-requests/323/from
 * [new ref]           refs/pull-requests/323/merge -> refs/pull-requests/323/merge
 * [new ref]           refs/pull-requests/344/from  -> refs/pull-requests/344/from
 * [new ref]           refs/pull-requests/344/merge -> refs/pull-requests/344/merge
 * [new ref]           refs/pull-requests/350/from  -> refs/pull-requests/350/from
 * [new ref]           refs/pull-requests/350/merge -> refs/pull-requests/350/merge
 * [new ref]           refs/pull-requests/355/from  -> refs/pull-requests/355/from
 * [new ref]           refs/pull-requests/355/merge -> refs/pull-requests/355/merge
```

`*/from` gives you PR branch heads; `*/merge` gives you the result of merging the PR with your target branch.

For more details, see [Pull request proficiency: Fetching abilities unlocked!](https://www.atlassian.com/git/articles/pull-request-proficiency-fetching-abilities-unlocked)

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48806891/bitbucket-does-not-update-refspec-for-pr-causing-jenkins-to-build-old-commits/48823808#48823808) for why it may be a bad idea.

Answer (score 3):

This is unsupported by Bitbucket: https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issues/5814/reify-pull-requests-by-making-them-a-ref

Answer (score 1):

**Supported by Bitbucket Server (Stash) (Self-hosted)**

Stash supports refspecs and is available thru the following command

```
git config --add remote.origin.fetch '+refs/pull-requests//from:refs/remotes/origin/pr/'
```

You can check against your .git/config file to see if it's setup properly

```
[remote "upstream"]
url = git@stash.atlassian.com:docker/libswarm.git
fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/upstream/*
fetch = +refs/pull-requests/*/from:refs/remotes/upstream/pr/*
```

https://www.atlassian.com/blog/archives/how-to-fetch-pull-requests

**Unsupported by Bitbucket Cloud (bitbucket.com)**

Bitbucket Cloud currently do not support PR on refspec, available option would be to either Poll Bitbucket's Git or API Endpoint

https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BCLOUD-5814

Given that the request have been on hold for 7 years it would be wise to not wait for the refspec implementation (as of Nov 2019)

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48806891/bitbucket-does-not-update-refspec-for-pr-causing-jenkins-to-build-old-commits/48823808#48823808) for why it may be a bad idea.