# BitBucket does not update refspec for PR, causing Jenkins to build old commits

Tags: git, jenkins, continuous-integration, bitbucket, pull-request

I am using a local BitBucket server with Git. I am trying to get started with Continous Integration so I've set up a local Jenkins instance. The goal is to have Jenkins check out pull-requests and build the project, and then report back to BitBucket with the result.

In BitBucket I am using [Webhook to Jenkins for Stash](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.nerdwin15.stash-stash-webhook-jenkins/server/overview) which notifies my Jenkins instance each time a pull-request is created/updated.

In Jenkins i am using [Stash pullrequest builder plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Stash+pullrequest+builder+plugin) to have Jenkins checkout the pullrequest, when notified from the plugin above. I have used the settings in the documentation, i.e.

```
Refspec: +refs/pull-requests/*:refs/remotes/origin/pr/*
Branch Specifier: origin/pr/${pullRequestId}/from
```

It almost works...

When i create a new pull request in BitBucket, Jenkins get nofitied, checks out the PR and report the result back to BitBucket. So far so good.

However when I update the PR (i.e. commit new code and push to BitBucket), Jenkins gets triggered but still checks out the previous commit in the PR, and not the new commit.

I've done some investegation but got stuck. From what I understand `Refspec` specifies that i should map `refs/remotes/origin/pr/*` to `refs/pull-requests/*` locally. However it does not seem like BitBucket updates the refs for the PR when i do a new commit to an existing PR, which causes Jenkins only to find the old one.

When I run `git ls-remote origin` after commiting and pushing an update to an existing PR i get this:

```
edf245 (new commit)...             refs/heads/feature/Name-Of-My-Branch-That-I-Created-Pull-Request-From-pr
af774f (previous commit in PR)...  refs/pull-requests/69/from
7fa82b (master)...                 refs/pull-requests/69/merge
```

However after visiting the PR-page in BitBucket, the refs seems to be updated and i get the following result:

```
edf245 (new commit)...             refs/heads/feature/Name-Of-My-Branch-That-I-Created-Pull-Request-From-pr
edf245 (new commit)...             refs/pull-requests/69/from
7fa82b (master)...                 refs/pull-requests/69/merge
```

And if i manually trigger Jenkins after this it build the latest commit.

So my problem is that BitBucket does not seem to upfate the refspec until I visit the acutal PR-page in BitBucket. How can i fix this?

Googling the problem I ended up [here](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/Change-pull-request-refs-after-Commit-instead-of-after-Approval/qaq-p/194702) where it seems like the behaviour is by design...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See Daves answer for an explanation on why this "problem" arise and why Bitbucket is designed in this way.

However i was able to solve my specific problem by changing the settings in the Jenkin-plugin, to "trick" Bitbucket into updating the refs.

By setting the option `Build only if Stash reports no conflicts` to true in Jenkins (Under `Build Trigger` for the job), you force Bitbucket to update the refs which means you will check out the correct commit

See https://github.com/nemccarthy/stash-pullrequest-builder-plugin/issues/75 for details

Answer (score 5):

Full disclosure: I work for Atlassian's Premier Support team.

First of all, this isn't a bug - it's worth noting that pull request refs (under `refs/pull-requests/*`) are an implementation detail of Bitbucket Server. They are not intended to be used for CI, or generally relied upon for development. [This comment](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BSERV-3196?focusedCommentId=452801&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-452801) by one of our developers lists some of the reasons why it might not be a good idea to build these refs in CI.

To give you a more technical background, these refs are only created when the pull requests are viewed - they're not eagerly created. Further, the refs under `/refs/pull-requests/*` may be updated at any time - any change to the source or target branch will result in the pull request being rescoped, but this rescoping event is not guaranteed to be instantaneous and may be enqueued alongside other system events. This is one of the main reasons why we don't recommend building off them. There are other good reasons not to build off these refs - considering the following scenario:

- Sarah at Apple opens PR #123 in **ios-core**, to merge **feature/hologram-ui-support** into **develop** (I know, I'm a dreamer)
- `refs/pull-requests/123` is created, and a CI build runs for the **feature/hologram-ui-support** PR
- Meanwhile, Ahmed merges **bug/weird-apfs-edge-case** into develop. This causes `refs/pull-requests/123` to be rescoped because the target branch has changed, and another CI build runs for the **feature/hologram-ui-support** PR
- Jane merges **feature/siri-asimov-laws-of-robotics-support** into **develop**. `refs/pull-requests/123` is rescoped again, and another CI build runs for the **feature/hologram-ui-support** PR

You can see what I mean - because those refs get rescoped on changes to the target as well as the source branch, it results in a lot more CI builds than you might be expecting. This is likely to be very taxing for your CI server, as effectively every merged PR will trigger a build of every open PR.

Generally speaking I'd recommend one of two approaches:

1. Build the *merge* in your CI build:

   - Trigger builds on changes to the source branch, and have your build plan do something like `git checkout target; git merge source` as a build step. Most CI systems should have native support for this kind of workflow.
2. If you must build off `refs/pull-requests/`, do so only on `refs/pull-requests/<id>/merge-clean`. There are other merge types here that are inherently failure cases: `merge-conflicted` and `merge-base`, so there's no point even trying to build those.

Cheers,

Dave

Comment: Thank you Dave for the thorough explanation on why i have this issue and why it is designed by that. I have found sort of a workaround to solve specific problem to "trick" Bitbucket into updating the refs by, se my answer to this question for details