# How to update local checkedout PR code with the latest commits into PR?

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-pull, git-fetch

I have checked out a PR into my local. Now the PR got updated, how do I update the local branch with the latest commit.
When I try to do
`git fetch upstream`
`git pull origin`
all of them are saying the branch is not present. And that is because it is a PR and not a branch. How do I update my local repo?

Comment: A pull request in Bitbucket (or GitHub) is a phenomenon specific to the repo, not to Git, and certainly not to the local Git running on your machine.  You should be able to update a branch which is in pull request review, and the PR should automatically get updated.  If you can't pull or push, maybe there is a problem, but I think it is related to something else.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Checkout bitbucket pull requests locally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25967034/checkout-bitbucket-pull-requests-locally)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bbitbucket%5D+pull+request+locally

Answer (score 0):

When you [check out a PR locally](https://help.github.com/en/github/collaborating-with-issues-and-pull-requests/checking-out-pull-requests-locally), you are fetching a branch in a specific namespace:

```
git fetch origin pull/ID/head:BRANCHNAME
# or
git fetch upstream pull/ID/head:BRANCHNAME
```

But if you do a git config -l, you will probably see a setting like:

```
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

The **[refspec](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-The-Refspec)** associated to your remote fetch branches, not `pull/branches`.

You would need to add (for GitHub pull requests):

```
fetch = +refs/pull/*/head:refs/remotes/origin/pr/*
```

In order to be able to fetch any `pr` branch.

For [**BitBucket** pull request](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58655632/6309):

```
fetch = +refs/pull-requests/*/from:refs/remotes/upstream/pr/*
```

(provided [BitBucket does refresh its PR branch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48806891/6309))

Answer (score 0):

You can **update/pull your checked-out un-merged PR Branch** by :

```
git pull upstream pull/PR-NUMBER/head:LOCAL-PR-BRANCH

example : git pull upstream pull/352/head:pr-352
```

FYI:
**How to checkout an unmerged PR:**

```
git fetch upstream pull/352/head:pr-352
git checkout pr-352
```

- remote can either be upstream or origin
- 352 is PR number
- pr-352 is local branch name into which PR is checked-out